# CornerRadius doesn't work when fliping UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, cornerradius

My view looks fine before a flip. but when I flip, it looks different than I expected.
What should I do to make the corner looks rounded even when I'm flipping it?

**corner looks bad**

[image: corner looks bad]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and review [ask].

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.